# Matrix Pagination 'next' link links to empty page

Tags: matrix, pagination

Sorry, new code.

I have created a new channel - gallery. This channel has 4 custom fields - {gallery_page_heading}, {gallery_sub_heading}, {gallery_image} and {gallery_page_content}, {gallery_image} being my Matrix field. I also have a new template - gallery_page.

The code in my gallery_page template is as follows:

```
{embed="includes/site_header"}

{embed="includes/brand_and_nav"}

<div id="pageHeading">
    <div class="wrap">
        {exp:channel:entries channel="gallery" limit="1" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
        <h1>{gallery_page_heading}</h1>
        <p>{gallery_sub_heading}</p>
    </div><!-- End wrap -->
</div><!-- End pageHeading -->

<div id="content">
    <div id="contentWrap" class="clearfix">
        <div id="mainContent">
            <div id="breadcrumb">
                <p>You are here: {exp:structure:breadcrumb inc_here="yes" here_as_title="yes" add_last_class="no"}</p>
            </div><!-- End breadcrumb -->
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {gallery_page_content} 
        {/exp:channel:entries}

        {preload_replace:rows_per_page="3"}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="gallery" url_title="{segment_3}" dynamic="no"}    
            {if gallery_image}
                <div id="gallery" class="clearfix">
                    {gallery_image offset="{segment_4}" limit="{rows_per_page}"}
                        <div class="{switch="galleryImage|galleryImage|galleryImageLast"}">
                            <a href="{big_image}" rel="lightbox-gallery" title="{image_caption}"><img src="{small_image}" alt="{image_title}" /></a>
                        </div>
                    {/gallery_image}    
                </div><!-- End gallery -->
                {if segment_4 > rows_per_page}
                    <a href="{page_url/}/{exp:simple_math calculate='{segment_4}-{rows_per_page}'}">
                    Prev
                    </a>
                {/if}

                {if "{gallery_image:total_rows}" > "{exp:simple_math calculate='{segment_4}+{rows_per_page}'}"}
                    <a href="{page_url}/{if segment_4}{exp:simple_math calculate='{segment_4}+{rows_per_page}'}{if:else}{rows_per_page}{/if}">
                    Next
                    </a>
                {/if}
            {/if}
        {/exp:channel:entries}     

        </div><!-- End mainContent -->

        {embed="includes/site_sidebar"} 

{embed="includes/site_footer"}
```

The images display on the page as they should, the 'next' pagination link displays when it should but it still links to an empty page. The gallery is currently held at `www.example.com/development/nails/gallery-test/` and when the 'next' link is clicked the url changes to `www.example.com/development/nails/gallery-test/3`. This page doesn't exist though and doesn't show the remainder of the images.

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working via lots of help from Lisa Wess (legend) and [Freebie][1]. I installed Freebie and set the 'Freebie Segments' to the number of images I wanted per page in my gallery. I then substituted all {segment_x} tags with {freebie_x} tags and changed some conditionals from my previous code above.

My new template code:

```
             {preload_replace:rows_per_page="3"}
                {exp:channel:entries channel="gallery" url_title="{freebie_2}" dynamic="no"}    
                    {if gallery_image}
                        <div id="gallery" class="clearfix">
                            {gallery_image offset="{freebie_3}" limit="{rows_per_page}"}
                                <div class="{switch="galleryImage|galleryImage|galleryImageLast"}">
                                    <a href="{big_image}" rel="lightbox-gallery" title="{image_title}"><img src="{small_image}" alt="{image_title}" /></a>
                                </div>
                    {/gallery_image}    
                        </div><!-- End gallery -->

                    {if freebie_3 == '3'}
                        <a href="{page_url}/">
                        Prev
                        </a>
                    {if:elseif freebie_3 > rows_per_page} 
                        <a href="{page_url}/{exp:simple_math calculate='{freebie_3}-{rows_per_page}'}">
                        Prev
                        </a>   
                    {/if}

                    {if "{gallery_image:total_rows}" > "{exp:simple_math calculate='{freebie_3}+{rows_per_page}'}"}
                        <a href="{page_url}/{if freebie_3}{exp:simple_math calculate='{freebie_3}+{rows_per_page}'}{if:else}{rows_per_page}{/if}">
                        Next
                        </a>
                    {/if}
                    {/if}
                {/exp:channel:entries}     

            </div><!-- End mainContent -->
```

Because my gallery was located at www.mysite.com/development/nails/gallery-test/ I had to change some of the {segment_x}/{freebie_x} tags back one, so from {segment_4}/{freebie_4} to {segment_3}/{freebie_3}, previously the code was looking at the wrong url segment.

I hope this explanation saves anyone else from running into this issue with Structure and Matrix image galleries with pagination.

Thanks again to Lisa Wess for all her help!

Comment: WOOT!  So glad to see you got this working. Thank you for posting that awesome answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Updating my answer.  I've logged in and done some troubleshooting.  I think that the problem with pagination is stemming potentially from using a Structure Page_URL for this.

I set up a template group and template: pt_test/pag and put this code in it:

```
 {preload_replace:rows_per_page="3"}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="gallery" url_title="{segment_3}" dynamic="no"}    
        <h1><a href="{url_title_path='pt_test/pag'}">{title}: {url_title}</a>: segment 3: {segment_3}, segment 4: {segment_4}</h1>
        {page_url}<br />
            {if gallery_image}
                <div id="gallery" class="clearfix">
                    {gallery_image offset="{segment_4}" limit="{rows_per_page}"}
                        <div class="{switch="galleryImage|galleryImage|galleryImageLast"}">
                            <a href="{big_image}" rel="lightbox-gallery" title="{image_caption}">{row_id}<img src="{small_image}" alt="{image_title}" /></a>
                        </div>
                    {/gallery_image}    
                </div><!-- End gallery -->


{if segment_4 > rows_per_page}
  <a href="{path='pt_test/pag/{url_title}'}/{exp:simple_math calculate='{segment_4}-{rows_per_page}'}">
    Prev
  </a>
{/if}

{if "{gallery_image:total_rows}" > "{exp:simple_math calculate='{segment_4}+{rows_per_page}'}"}
  <a href="{path='pt_test/pag/{url_title}'}/{if segment_4}{exp:simple_math calculate='{segment_4}+{rows_per_page}'}{if:else}{rows_per_page}{/if}">
    Next
  </a>
{/if}

            {/if}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
```

If you visit this on the front-end and use the next and previous links, then you'll see that the pagination is working.  I built the Next and Previous links a bit differently than you had, and I've got some diagnostics outputting by echoing out those segments to see what EE sees.  But I think you should be able to take this working template and build from there.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I set dynamic to "no" and change it to {segment_4} none of my gallery images show. When dynamic = "yes" the images show but the links takes me to an empty page. Adding exactly `{exp:channel:entries dynamic="no" url_title="{segment_3}"}` and changing `{segment_3} to {segment_4}` displays all the images from all my galleries, not just the gallery on that page/entry.

Comment: Can you update your code with the changes, please? Thank you!

Comment: Done. I think it might be to do with me not having a separate channel for my galleries? My 'page' channel/template has the following custom fields `{page_heading}`, `{page_sub_heading}`, `{page_content}`, `{page_gallery}`, `{page_faq}` and  `{page_sidebar_options}` and this template is used for most pages on the site, which is built with Structure. Sorry if I am blabbing on but I have been stuck with this for nearly 4 days :(

Comment: I've now added a channel for my galleries called "gallery", again everything displays as I would expect it to but when I click the next link it takes me to a blank page. The link is www.example.com/development/nails/gallery-test/ and when I click the next button the link changes to www.example.com/development/nails/gallery-test/3 but just links to an empty page. Thanks!

Comment: Stephen - can you update your original question with the current code you're testing with, please? Thank you!

Comment: Stephen - is this something you'd be willing to let me look at directly? If so, can you email support@pixelandtonic.com with Superadmin details? Thank you!

Comment: I've updated my answer Stephen. :) Please have a read!

Comment: Thanks Lisa. The solution you have suggested does work, but unfortunately it does not work with Structure. If anyone else has come across this issue I'd love to hear what they did to make it function. Thanks again.

Comment: Aha, I saw your post over on GetSat.  Have you chatted with the Structure folks about this at all?  They may have some ideas too.

Comment: Stephen, make sure you're on the latest version of Structure.  I found some pagination issues reported/fixed in older versions and want to make sure you're not running afoul of those. :)

Comment: Hi Lisa, I've posted a new topic in their forums but they haven't got back to me as of yet. I'm on Structure 3.3.7, I see there is a new release, I'll upgrade to that to see if that helps. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Stephen, I did some more searching around and came across this tutorial, which uses Freebie:

http://www.idfive.com/blog/2011/02/matrix-structure-freebie-expression-engine-image-gallery/

I am wondering if that might be the answer you're looking for.  :)

-Lisa

Comment: OK, cool, I'll have a look at that and see if that helps. I'll let you know the outcome. Thanks :)

Comment: Got it working Lisa, posted my answer below. Again, thanks for all your help, couldn't have done it without you! Stephen.