# Pagination with Matrix fields?

Tags: matrix, pagination

I hear rumors that this is possible.

I want to set up a photo gallery that only shows 10 of 100+ photos. User click paginated links to see more photos.

Anybody ever have to set this up? I hear a rumor it requires Simple Math?

If you have a solution, share it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple pagination with only a previous and next button example. It should give you a good place to start. The example uses pagination number in the 3rd segment and instead of Simple Math uses [Math](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/math) plugin. May have over commented, but:

```
{!--   how many matrix rows per page?   --}
{preload_replace:rows_per_page="2"}

{exp:channel:entries channel="YOUR_CHANNEL" url_title="YOUR_URL_TITLE" dynamic="no"} 

    {if YOUR_MATRIX_FIELD}

        {!--   matrix rows   --}
        {YOUR_MATRIX_FIELD offset="{segment_3}" limit="{rows_per_page}"}
            {cell_1}<br>
            {cell_2}<br>
            {cell_3}
            {!--   etc...   --}
            <hr>
        {/YOUR_MATRIX_FIELD}    

        {!-- ---------------------- 
        previous link 
        ---------------------- --}
        {!--   if we're on the second page   --}
        {if "{segment_3}" == "{rows_per_page}"} 
            <a href="{path='YOUR_TEMPLATE_GROUP/YOUR_TEMPLATE'}">Prev</a>  

        {!--   else if we're further along in pages   --} 
        {if:elseif "{segment_3}" > "{rows_per_page}"} 
            <a href="{path='YOUR_TEMPLATE_GROUP/YOUR_TEMPLATE/{exp:math formula='{segment_3} - {rows_per_page}' absolute='yes'}'}">Prev</a>   
        {/if}

        {!-- ---------------------- 
        next link 
        ---------------------- --}
        {!--   if the total matrix rows are greater than sum of pagination segment plus rows per page   --}
        {if "{YOUR_MATRIX_FIELD:total_rows}" > "{exp:math formula='{segment_3} + {rows_per_page}' absolute='yes'}"}
            {!--   if not on the first page calculate next page segment, else show link to second page   --}
            <a href="{path='YOUR_TEMPLATE_GROUP/YOUR_TEMPLATE/{if segment_3}{exp:math formula='{segment_3} + {rows_per_page}' absolute='yes'}{if:else}{rows_per_page}{/if}'}">Next</a>   
        {/if}

    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

(this example builds on a related answer [here](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5496/matrix-pagination-next-link-links-to-empty-page))

Answer (score 0):

First don't get it to work (next area)
{YOUR_MATRIX_FIELD:total_rows} returns the entry of cell_1 if I use

if "{{YOUR_MATRIX_FIELD limit="1"}{field_total_rows}{/YOUR_MATRIX_FIELD}}" > "{exp:math formula='{segment_3} + {rows_per_page}' absolute='yes'}"}

It works fine